# Why is this site redirects to my localhost at ubuntu?

Tags: dns, redirection, localhost

Help understand why http://dkif.netadsopt.com/ redirects to my localhost at Ubuntu?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The only reason that would happen is if navigating to the domain on the server itself.

Comment: Can tou clarify a little bit?

Comment: Why downvotes? is the question out of place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because that host has a DNS record that points to localhost:

```
$ host dkif.netadsopt.com
dkif.netadsopt.com has address 127.0.0.2
```

Comment: So it also redirects you to localhost?

Comment: Of course. Why wouldn't it?

Comment: Why does such thing happen. How a machine on the web has Ip of local machine?

Comment: DNS servers can return anything they like. You can set up a domain to return the IP address of google.com if you want.

Comment: Aha, you just put redirect to 127.0.0.1 in your dns settings. Thanks, I though it may be an attack of virus..

Comment: This is only partly right.  It's only Google's DNS who's doing that redirect to 127.0.0.2, and it's (most likely) because the site that hosted it (which is normally at 54.72.9.51) is [known to be full of infections](https://www.virustotal.com/en/ip-address/54.72.9.51/information/).

Comment: So what do you suggest to do in order to completely exclude the risk of virus or attack as for now?

Answer (score -1):

You can try [flushing your DNS cache](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/07/flush-dns-cache-ubuntu-13-04-12-10/) as this guide suggests.

Open a terminal and run:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/dns-clean restart
```

Also:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking force-reload
```

In addition, to flush nscd dns cache:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/nscd restart
```

To flush dnsmasq dns cache:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/dnsmasq restart
```

Also, take a look at your `/etc/hosts` file to see if the site you try to access is not being mapped to your `localhost`. This file holds a map of names and IPs so your computer doesn't have to make a DNS request everytime it needs to resolve a name into an address. I also strongly encourage the use of [Google's Public DNS Servers](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/?hl=es): `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, by the way you wrote that you cannot access that site. But were you redirected to your localhost?

Comment: Thanks also for Google Pyblic DNS servers. I did not know about them

Comment: No, I weren't. I was just greeted by a page saying that the website is unavailable. I'm using google's DNSs though.

Comment: THis may be a reason